# RStan toolchain error on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, stan, rstan

I installed RStan, had a problem, uninstalled it, and then tried reinstalling it using https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Mac-or-Linux

However, when I try using rstan, I  get this error:

> Error in library(rstan) : there is no package called ‘rstan’

I noticed when I run the toolchain diagnostic mentioned on the above page,

```
fx <- inline::cxxfunction( signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric" ) , '
    return ScalarReal( INTEGER(x)[0] * REAL(y)[0] ) ;
' )
fx( 2L, 5 ) # should be 10
```

I get an error:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-arch x86_64'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-arch x86_64'
file16777e2261ec.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [file16777e2261ec.so] Error 1
ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!
Program source:
  1: 
  2: // includes from the plugin
  3: #include <R.h>
  4: #include <Rdefines.h>
  5: #include <R_ext/Error.h>
  6: 
  7: 
  8: // user includes
  9:     
 10: 
 11: // declarations
 12: extern "C" {
 13: SEXP file16777e2261ec( SEXP x, SEXP y) ;
 14: }
 15: 
 16: // definition
 17: 
 18: SEXP file16777e2261ec( SEXP x, SEXP y ){
 19: 
 20:    return ScalarReal( INTEGER(x)[0] * REAL(y)[0] ) ;
 21:  
 22: Rf_warning("your C++ program does not return anything"); 
 23:  return R_NilValue ; 
 24: }
 25: 
 26: 
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-arch x86_64'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-arch x86_64'
file16777e2261ec.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [file16777e2261ec.so] Error 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB file16777e2261ec.cpp 2> file16777e2261ec.cpp.err.txt' had status 1 

Error in fx(2L, 5) : could not find function "fx"
```

What is going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: To post code: In a text editor, shift it right four spaces, then copy and paste into your post.  Best to avoid using tabs.

Comment: What is in your `~/.R/Makevars` file?